# SOLR 9.4 "using sys-prop" when Enabling Remote Stream and Stream Body

Tags: solr

I am upgrading from Solr 8.11.1 to Solr 9.4.

I have Solr 9.4 up and running.

I'm loading an 8.11.1 core in 9.4 where I have remote streaming and remote body turned on in solrconfig.xml:

```
<requestParsers enableRemoteStreaming="true"         
                    enableStreamBody="true"     
                    multipartUploadLimitInKB="2048000"
                    formdataUploadLimitInKB="2048"
                    addHttpRequestToContext="false"/>
```

When I load the core, I get the following messages in the log:

```
SolrConfig - Ignored deprecated enableRemoteStreaming in config; use sys-prop
SolrConfig - Ignored deprecated enableStreamBody in config; use sys-prop
```

How do I use sys-prop to configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the standard `bin/solr` script, you [can set the environment variables](https://github.com/apache/solr/blob/51c8280cade92e6cc0b71aaf9bf34cd2c357f94e/solr/bin/solr#L1411) `SOLR_ENABLE_REMOTE_STREAMING` and `SOLR_ENABLE_STREAM_BODY` to `true` before starting the script - that will set the system properties for the JVM when starting it:

```
# Remote streaming and stream body
if [ "${SOLR_ENABLE_REMOTE_STREAMING:-false}" == "true" ]; then
  SCRIPT_SOLR_OPTS+=("-Dsolr.enableRemoteStreaming=true")
fi
if [ "${SOLR_ENABLE_STREAM_BODY:-false}" == "true" ]; then
  SCRIPT_SOLR_OPTS+=("-Dsolr.enableStreamBody=true")
fi
```

If you're not using the `bin/solr` script, you'll have to give those properties yourself as arguments to `java` when starting the instance (as you would with any other system property).